# UnsupportedApiCallException: Missing Feature{name=auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, version=8}

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

my project is news app in which I integrate Firebase authentication (google sign in and sign up with email and password).

When I'm clicking image button I want to navigate to news screen in which I want to display user's avatar on the right screens corner.

But unfortunately I've an exception which is on the title.

I want to say that I was trying :

SHA1 is correct;

client id is correct;

google-services file is in correct directory;

try to change firebase versions.

Here is my solution , but I think that something went wrong with or coroutines :

here is my repository

```
class AuthorizationRepositoryImpl@Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val oneTapClient:SignInClient,
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore
) : AuthorizationRepository {

    override suspend fun gmailAuth(credential: AuthCredential): Flow<AuthSignInResult> {
       return flow {
          val result = firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()
           val isNewUser = result.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser ?:false
           if(isNewUser){
               addUserToFireStore()
           }
           emit(
               AuthSignInResult(
               errorInSignIn = null,
               successful = result.toString()
           )
           )
       }.catch {
           AuthSignInResult(
               errorInSignIn = it.message,
               successful = null
           )
       }
    }

    private suspend fun addUserToFireStore() {
        firebaseAuth.currentUser?.apply {
            val user = toUser()
            db.collection(GoogleUserData(
                id = uid,
                name = displayName,
                picture = photoUrl.toString()
            ).toString()).document(uid).set(user).await()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun registration(email: String, password: String): Flow<AuthSignInResult> {
        return flow {
         val result = firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()

            val isNewUser = result.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser ?:false
            if(isNewUser){
                addUserToFireStore()
            }
          emit(
              AuthSignInResult(
                  errorInSignIn = null,
                  successful = result.toString()
              )
          )
    }.catch {
            AuthSignInResult(
                errorInSignIn = it.message,
                successful = null
            )
        }
}




    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    override suspend fun loginUser(email: String, password: String): Flow<AuthSignInResult> {
   return flow {
     val authres =  firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
       if(authres.user?.email?.let {
               DefaultAuthorizationData(
                   email = it,
                   password = it,
                   id = it
               )
           } != null){
           emit(AuthSignInResult(
               errorInSignIn = null,
               successful = authres.user.toString()
           ))
       }else{
           emit(AuthSignInResult(
               errorInSignIn = "User's data is wrong",
               successful = null
           ))
       }
   }.catch {
       AuthSignInResult(
           errorInSignIn = it.message,
           successful = null
       )
   }
    }



    override suspend fun signOut(): Flow<AuthSignInResult> = flow {
        oneTapClient.signOut().await()
        firebaseAuth.signOut()
        emit(AuthSignInResult(
            errorInSignIn = null,
            Loading = false,
            successful = oneTapClient.signOut().toString()
        ))
    }.catch {
        emit(AuthSignInResult(
            errorInSignIn = it.message,
            Loading = false,
            successful = null
        ))
    }



    fun FirebaseUser.toUser()=GoogleUserData(
    name = displayName,
    picture = photoUrl.toString(),
    id = uid
)

}
```

---

this is my viewmodel

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthorizationViewModel@Inject constructor(
    private val authorizationRepository: AuthorizationRepository,
    val oneTapClient:SignInClient,
    private val signInByGmail: BeginSignInRequest,
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    ) :ViewModel() {

private val _stateAuthentificationDefault = MutableStateFlow(AuthSignInResult())
    val stateAuthenticationDefault = _stateAuthentificationDefault.asStateFlow()

private val _loginState = Channel<AuthSignInState>()
val loginState = _loginState.receiveAsFlow()

private val validateEmail : ValidateEmail = ValidateEmail()
private val validatePassword:ValidateUsersPassword = ValidateUsersPassword()

 var validationFieldsState by mutableStateOf(UserDataValidation())
 private val validationEventChannel = Channel<ValidationConfirmEvent>()
 val validEvents = validationEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()


fun checkEvent(event:UsersDataEvent){
    when(event){
        is UsersDataEvent.EmailChanged->{
            validationFieldsState = validationFieldsState.copy(
                email = event.email
            )
        }
        is UsersDataEvent.PasswordChanged->{
            validationFieldsState = validationFieldsState.copy(
                password = event.password
            )
        }
        is UsersDataEvent.UserEnteredAllData->{
            checkdata()
        }
    }
}

    private fun checkdata() {
      val enteredEmail = validateEmail.isEmailValid(validationFieldsState.email)
      val enteredPassword = validatePassword.isPasswordValid(validationFieldsState.password)
       val hasError = listOf(
           enteredEmail,
           enteredPassword
       ).any {
           !it.successful
       }
        if(hasError){
            validationFieldsState.copy(
               emailError = enteredEmail.errorMessage,
                passwordError = enteredPassword.errorMessage
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
  validationEventChannel.send(ValidationConfirmEvent.Success)
        }
    }


    fun gmailAuth(credential: AuthCredential){
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
           authorizationRepository.gmailAuth(credential).collect{
                   result->

               if(result.successful != null){
                   _stateAuthentificationDefault.value = AuthSignInResult(
                       result.successful
                   )
               }else{
                   _stateAuthentificationDefault.value =
                       AuthSignInResult(errorInSignIn = result.errorInSignIn)
               }

           }
   }
}


   suspend fun SigninWithGmail():IntentSender{
       val signInResult  = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInByGmail)
      return signInResult.await().pendingIntent.intentSender
    }

    fun signOut(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            authorizationRepository.signOut().collect{
                     result->

                if(result.successful != null){
                    _stateAuthentificationDefault.value = AuthSignInResult(
                        result.successful
                    )
                }else{
                    _stateAuthentificationDefault.value =
                        AuthSignInResult(errorInSignIn = result.errorInSignIn)
                }
            }
        }
    }


fun LoginUser(email:String,password:String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
authorizationRepository.loginUser(email, password).collect{
        result->

    if(result.successful != null){
        _stateAuthentificationDefault.value = AuthSignInResult(
            result.successful
        )
    }else{
        _stateAuthentificationDefault.value =
            AuthSignInResult(errorInSignIn = result.errorInSignIn)
    }
}
    }

}




suspend fun RegisterUserByDefaultMethod(email:String,password: String):IntentSender{
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        authorizationRepository.registration(email, password).collect{
                result->

            if(result.successful != null){
                _stateAuthentificationDefault.value = AuthSignInResult(
                    result.successful
                )
            }else{
                _stateAuthentificationDefault.value =
                    AuthSignInResult(errorInSignIn = result.errorInSignIn)
            }
        }
    }
   return oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInByGmail).await().pendingIntent.intentSender
}
   fun getAlreadySignInUser():GoogleUserData? = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.toUser()

    }


fun FirebaseUser.toUser()= GoogleUserData(
    name = displayName,
    picture = photoUrl.toString(),
    id = uid
)

sealed class ValidationConfirmEvent{
    object Success:ValidationConfirmEvent()
}
```

---

This is my UI layer

```
package ui.screens
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.CircularProgressIndicator
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextButton
import androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion.Center
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion.CenterHorizontally
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.PasswordVisualTransformation
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import coil.compose.AsyncImage
import com.example.firebasetesting.R
import ui.padding.customSpacing
import ui.presentation.state.UsersDataEvent
import ui.screens.screensviewmodels.AuthorizationViewModel
import ui.screens.screensviewmodels.ValidationConfirmEvent



@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@SuppressLint("StateFlowValueCalledInComposition")
@Composable
fun SignUpScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, navigateToLogin: () -> Unit,
                 navigateToGoogleSignIn: () -> Unit,navigateFromDefaultAuth: () -> Unit) {
val context = LocalContext.current
    val viewmodel = hiltViewModel<AuthorizationViewModel>()

    val gmailState = viewmodel.stateAuthenticationDefault.value

val checkForValidationState = viewmodel.validationFieldsState

    Column(modifier.fillMaxSize(),verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = CenterHorizontally) {


        LaunchedEffect(key1 = gmailState.successful){
            if(gmailState.successful != null){
                val success = gmailState.successful
                Log.d("TAG","It was ${success}")
            }
        }




        LaunchedEffect(key1 = gmailState.errorInSignIn){
            if(gmailState.errorInSignIn != null){
                val error = gmailState.errorInSignIn
                Log.d("TAG","It was ${error}")
            }
        }



        LaunchedEffect(key1 = context){
            viewmodel.validEvents.collect{
                event->
                when(event){
                    is ValidationConfirmEvent.Success->{
                        Log.d("TAG","SIGN UP has been successfully done")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

       if(gmailState.Loading){
          Box(contentAlignment = Center){
              CircularProgressIndicator()
          }
       }


LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
    if(gmailState.successful != null){
        Log.d("TAG","Authentication has been done")
    }
}

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = checkForValidationState.email, onValueChange = {
          viewmodel.checkEvent(UsersDataEvent.EmailChanged(it))
        },
        modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        label = { Text(text = "Email",
        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.maintextfontinapp)),
            color = Color.Black
            )},
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter Email",
            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.maintextfontinapp)
            ),
            color = Color.Black
            )},
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email
        ),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(Color.White),
        isError = checkForValidationState.emailError != null,
    )

        if(checkForValidationState.emailError != null){
            Text(
                text = checkForValidationState.emailError,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier.padding(customSpacing.current.extraMedium))


    OutlinedTextField(
          value = checkForValidationState.password,
          onValueChange = {
          viewmodel.checkEvent(UsersDataEvent.PasswordChanged(it))
          },
          modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
          keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
             keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password
         ),
          label = { Text(text = "Password",
          fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.maintextfontinapp)),
              color = Color.Black
              )},
          placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter your password",
              fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.maintextfontinapp)),
              color = Color.Black)},
          singleLine = true,
          shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(Color.White),
visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        isError = checkForValidationState.passwordError != null,
    )

        if(checkForValidationState.passwordError != null){
            Text(
                text = checkForValidationState.passwordError,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
                )
        }

        Spacer(modifier.padding(customSpacing.current.medium))


        Button(
            onClick = navigateFromDefaultAuth,
            modifier
                .padding(customSpacing.current.medium)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
                    colors  = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.White),
        ){
            Text(
                text = "SIGN UP",
                color = Color.Black
            )

        }

            

        TextButton(onClick = navigateToLogin,
            modifier.padding(customSpacing.current.medium)){
            Text(text = "Already have account?",
                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.maintextfontinapp)),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                color = Color.White
            )
        }

        IconButton(onClick = navigateToGoogleSignIn) {
          AsyncImage(model =
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/" +
                  "588px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png?20230305195327",
              contentDescription = "Google Icon"
          )
        }
}
}
```

navigation logic

```
package ui.screens.screensviewmodels.navigation
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import ui.presentation.state.UsersDataEvent
import ui.screens.SignUpScreen
import ui.screens.BadInternet
import ui.screens.LoginScreen
import ui.screens.NewsScreen
import ui.screens.NoInternetScreen
import ui.screens.ProfileScreen
import ui.screens.screensviewmodels.AuthorizationViewModel
import ui.screens.screensviewmodels.NewsViewModel
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException


@SuppressLint("StateFlowValueCalledInComposition")
@Composable
fun CustomNavigationInApp() {
    val context = LocalContext.current.applicationContext
    val navigationScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val initializeScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val navController = rememberNavController()
    val authorizationViewModel = hiltViewModel<AuthorizationViewModel>()

    val newsViewModel = hiltViewModel<NewsViewModel>()


    val launcherGmail = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ){
            activityResult ->
        if(activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try {
                val credentials = authorizationViewModel.oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(
                    activityResult.data
                )
                val googleIdToken = credentials.googleIdToken
                val googleCred = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken,null)
            authorizationViewModel.gmailAuth(googleCred)
            }catch (e:Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
                if(e is CancellationException) throw e
            }
        }
    }


    val DefaultAuthLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ){
        activityResult ->
        if(activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try {
                val state = authorizationViewModel.stateAuthenticationDefault.value
              if(state.successful != null){
                  initializeScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
                      authorizationViewModel.RegisterUserByDefaultMethod(
                          email = authorizationViewModel.validationFieldsState.email,
                          password = authorizationViewModel.validationFieldsState.password
                      )
                  }
              }
            }catch (e:Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e("TAG","Error occurred ${e}")
            }
        }
    }



    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "registration_screen" ) {
        composable("registration_screen") {
            SignUpScreen(navigateToLogin = { navController.navigate("loginScreen") },
                navigateFromDefaultAuth = {
                    authorizationViewModel.checkEvent(UsersDataEvent.UserEnteredAllData)
                   navigationScope.launch{
                     DefaultAuthLauncher.launch(
                           IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                            authorizationViewModel.RegisterUserByDefaultMethod(
                                email = authorizationViewModel.validationFieldsState.email,
                                password = authorizationViewModel.validationFieldsState.password
                            )
                           ).build()
                       )
                       navController.navigate("news_screen")
                   }
                }, navigateToGoogleSignIn = {
                    navigationScope.launch {
                        val gmailAuthResult = authorizationViewModel.SigninWithGmail()
                        launcherGmail.launch(
                            IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                                gmailAuthResult
                            ).build()
                        )
                        navController.navigate("news_screen")
                    }

                }
            )

        }


        composable("loginScreen") {
            LoginScreen()
        }

        composable("news_screen") {
            NewsScreen(
                onProfileClick = {
                    navController.navigate("ProfileScreen")
                },
                googleUserData = authorizationViewModel.getAlreadySignInUser(),
                newsData = newsViewModel.newsState.value.news
                )
        }

        composable("noInternetScreen") {
            NoInternetScreen()
        }

        composable("badInternetScreen") {
            BadInternet()
        }
composable("ProfileScreen"){
    ProfileScreen(signOutClick = {
        navController.navigate("registration_screen")
    }, backToNewsScreen = {
        navController.popBackStack()
    })
}
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword). It's tested.

Comment: If you're looking to implement Firebase auth with email and password, then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: @AlexMamo , thx , for advices that you give me , but I'm already fixed that problem, and solution was to try app on real smartphone.